# AttributeError: 'DB_Connector' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a newbie to python and trying to create a class object for a database connection. I seem to be running into trouble when trying to access a variable from one function that was created in another function inside the class. Is this possible or am I going about it the wrong way? The code errors on the last line: db_results = oyn_conn.Execute(query) with an AttributeError listed in the heading

```
class DB_Connector(object):
def __init__(self, user,passwd,db):
    self.user = user
    self.passwd = passwd
    self.db = db
    self.CreateConnection

def CreateConnection(self):   
    self.cursor = mysql.connector.connect(user=self.user,password = self.password,database= self.db)

def Execute(self, sql_statement):
    self.cursor.execute(sql_statement)
    return self.cursor.fetchall()

query = "select venue_name,venue_id from venue where venue_id in('1435','345')"
oyn_conn = DB_Connector('root','password','oyn_db')
db_results = oyn_conn.Execute(query)
```

Comment: It seems you are missing parens in your call to CreateConnection. It should be `self.CreateConnection()`.

Answer (score -1):

Ok So I played around with it and found the answer, I had some sytax errors in my code:

```
class DB_Connector(object):
def __init__(self, user,passwd,db):
    self.user = user
    self.passwd = passwd
    self.db = db
    self.CreateConnection()

def CreateConnection(self):   
    self.cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=self.user,passwd = self.passwd,database= self.db)
    self.cursor = self.cnx.cursor()
    self.cnx._open_connection() 

def Execute(self, sql_statement):
    self.cursor.execute(sql_statement)
    return self.cursor.fetchall()

def DestroyConnection(self):
    self.cursor.close()

query = "select venue_name,venue_id from venue where venue_id 
in('1332343501255','1888841136809')"
oyn_conn = DB_Connector('root','password','oyn_db')
db_results = oyn_conn.Execute(query)
print(db_results)
oyn_conn.DestroyConnection()
```